# JMS client applications and the Business Activity Monitor

Tags: java, oracle, jms, weblogic, oracle-bam

I was wondering if there was a way to connect to the Business Activity Monitor located on a WebLogic server via the client applications. I am wanting to replace the log statements in my JMS Producer/Consumer clients with BAM statements so BAM is updated with message progress/errors? I am hoping there is an API for this, but have not been successful in locating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle BAM is able to consume [XML messages from a queue or a topic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/integration.1111/e10230/bam_intro.htm#CHDCAIFC) as input for a data item. Here is [BAM configuration documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/integration.1111/e10224/bam_ent_msg_sources.htm#SOASE1952) to do so.

As your client application is already JMS based, it should be easy to make them send additional JMS messages to a dedicated queue for progress monitoring in BAM.

Beware of the transaction demarcation: you have to take care if your BAM message is supposed to be included in the same transaction as your regular business or in a specific one, to avoid a rollback in case of business failure.

Comment: Thanks, I actually found this yesterday, but it's nice to have someone confirm that this is what it is used for.